# How to sort dynamically created GridViews in code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a dynamic number of Gridviews created based on user-entered data. Each of the Gridviews  has its own header row, and I want the user to be able to sort individual GridViews by clicking on a particular column's header. I've been having trouble writing an OnClick_sort method to reference the particular GridView and that data. Also, I want this to be done on Client-side instead of being passed back to the server, so I need to write the Sort method in a JavaScript, correct? Each GridView has a unique ID, generated when adding the GridView to the control.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by sing Jquery. Refer This...
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Headers-and-Client-Side-Sorting-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-GridView-Records-using-DropDownList-in-HeaderTemplate-Header-Row-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You should keep in memory the elements of the grid and sort it using your code (handling events and etc). But, the magic is: you should put your grid in a updatePanel, so your code will be translated to a script that will execute on the cliente side. If your code is too complex to run on the cliente, it will comunicate with the server without your intervension.

Is that? ;)